# When using a container, should I run git within the container or outside?

Tags: git, lando

I'm using Lando to generate a dev environment for my project. I'm just wondering if there's a best practice as to whether Git should be run from within the container (via `lando ssh`) or just from my dev machine?

Answer (score 0):

That depends. Probably inside your container is best unless you mount an external volume to your container. But then you will have to make sure your container has Git tools installed.